# JSON url undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, url

I have problem with this URL http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/category/tv-emisija/?json=get_all_posts
I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

But I haven't problem with this URL http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/category/vijesti/?json=get_all_posts

This is my code:

```
function json_parser_fun() {

    var url = 'http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/category/tv-emisija/?json=get_all_posts';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json){
                    console.debug(json);
                    var JSONstring = JSON.stringify(json);
                    var myData = JSON.parse(JSONstring);

                    var postovi = "";

                    var brojac = 1;
                    var ima = 0;

                    for(var i=0;i<myData.posts.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(brojac %2 ==0)
                            postovi = postovi + "<a onClick=moja_funkcija('"+ myData.posts[i].url +"') class='menu_item' href='#'><div class='menu_div"+2+"'><div class='image_div'><img style='height:40px;width:40px;' src='"+ myData.posts[i].attachments[0].url +"'/></div><div class='title_div'><p style='font-size:9px'>" + myData.posts[i].date + "</p><p style='font-size:12px'>" + myData.posts[i].title + "</p></div></div></a>";
                        else
                            postovi = postovi + "<a onClick=moja_funkcija('"+ myData.posts[i].url +"') class='menu_item' href='#'><div class='menu_div'><div class='image_div'><img style='height:40px;width:40px;' src='"+ myData.posts[i].attachments[0].url +"'/></div><div class='title_div'><p style='font-size:9px'>" + myData.posts[i].date + "</p><p style='font-size:12px'>" + myData.posts[i].title + "</p></div></div></a>";
                        brojac++;
                    }

                    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = postovi;
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error?  And, why in the world so you stringify and then parse?  You should be able to just use the returned javascript object because jQuery already parsed it for you.

Comment: myData.posts[i].url change this to myData.posts[i].attachments[0].url also check the length of attachments before accessing

Comment: it worked with me (on a fiddle), but I got another error `TypeError: myData.posts[i].attachments[0] is undefined` so check your JSON format

Comment: The posts[i].url is undefined add and alert or step through it to see what data is being returned

Comment: I removed attachments[0] and now it works good :)
Thank you

Comment: But now it is not showing pictures

Comment: You are not suppose to remove it,just check the length of attatchments and if it is 1 or more access it. Also remove the redundant JSON Parsing since you are already getting a JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON response sometimes attachments is empty.
[image]

Example #1: **empty attachments replaces to urlNo_attachments_url**

```
function json_parser_fun() {

    var url = 'http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/category/tv-emisija/?json=get_all_posts';
    var urlNo_attachments_url = 'http://animatika.ru/netcat_files/userfiles/3/facepalm.jpg';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json){
                    console.debug(json);
                    var JSONstring = JSON.stringify(json);
                    var myData = JSON.parse(JSONstring);

                    var postovi = "";

                    var brojac = 1;
                    var ima = 0;

                    for(var i=0;i<myData.posts.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(brojac %2 ==0)
                            postovi = postovi + "<a onClick=moja_funkcija('"+ myData.posts[i].url +"') class='menu_item' href='#'><div class='menu_div"+2+"'><div class='image_div'><img style='height:40px;width:40px;' src='"+ (myData.posts[i].attachments && myData.posts[i].attachments[0]?myData.posts[i].attachments[0].url:urlNo_attachments_url) +"'/></div><div class='title_div'><p style='font-size:9px'>" + myData.posts[i].date + "</p><p style='font-size:12px'>" + myData.posts[i].title + "</p></div></div></a>";
                        else
                            postovi = postovi + "<a onClick=moja_funkcija('"+ myData.posts[i].url +"') class='menu_item' href='#'><div class='menu_div'><div class='image_div'><img style='height:40px;width:40px;' src='"+ (myData.posts[i].attachments && myData.posts[i].attachments[0]?myData.posts[i].attachments[0].url:urlNo_attachments_url) +"'/></div><div class='title_div'><p style='font-size:9px'>" + myData.posts[i].date + "</p><p style='font-size:12px'>" + myData.posts[i].title + "</p></div></div></a>";
                        brojac++;
                    }

                    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = postovi;
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
        });
}
```

Example #2: **if empty attachments - post remove**

```
function json_parser_fun() {

    var url = 'http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/category/tv-emisija/?json=get_all_posts';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json){
                    console.debug(json);
                    var JSONstring = JSON.stringify(json);
                    var myData = JSON.parse(JSONstring);

                    var postovi = "";

                    var brojac = 1;
                    var ima = 0;

                    for(var i=0;i<myData.posts.length;i++)
                    {
            if(myData.posts[i].attachments && myData.posts[i].attachments[0]){
                        if(brojac %2 ==0)
                            postovi = postovi + "<a onClick=moja_funkcija('"+ myData.posts[i].url +"') class='menu_item' href='#'><div class='menu_div"+2+"'><div class='image_div'><img style='height:40px;width:40px;' src='"+ myData.posts[i].attachments[0].url +"'/></div><div class='title_div'><p style='font-size:9px'>" + myData.posts[i].date + "</p><p style='font-size:12px'>" + myData.posts[i].title + "</p></div></div></a>";
                        else
                            postovi = postovi + "<a onClick=moja_funkcija('"+ myData.posts[i].url +"') class='menu_item' href='#'><div class='menu_div'><div class='image_div'><img style='height:40px;width:40px;' src='"+ myData.posts[i].attachments[0].url +"'/></div><div class='title_div'><p style='font-size:9px'>" + myData.posts[i].date + "</p><p style='font-size:12px'>" + myData.posts[i].title + "</p></div></div></a>";
                        brojac++;
            }
                    }
                    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = postovi;
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
        });
}
```